# Select the input with value having backslash in javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field with following structure

The value attribute is dynamic . Its fetched from the server. Now i want to select this input selector with the value being fetched from server like this

```
<input type="checkbox" class="folderscheck" value="/content/dam/my-products/a-test">
```

document.querySelectorAll("input[value=something from server]");

Now problem is since the value has backslashes so not able to fetch it. How can we achieve this and match the value and get the selector.

Comment: `var inp = document.querySelector('input[value="/content/dam/my-products/a-test"]');` works fine.

Comment: "since the value has backslashes so not able to fetch it" [citation needed]. Please post the code that you tried that is not working. BTW, despite your title, there are no backslashes in your value.